# Datepicker does not triggers on default date selection in xamarin.forms - Android

Tags: c#, datepicker, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

While using DatePicker in xamarin.Forms I encountered a difficulty of knowing whether user have actually selected default date or datepicker just shows default date given by me. Since **datepicker**'s **DateSelected** event is triggered only if there is change in datepicker field , I want to get the date from datepicker only if user actually selects the date.

How can I achieve it?? Please comment if the question is not properly briefed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Xamarin.Forms** **DatePicker.Date** property can be set to a specific date, or left alone and it will populate with the current date.

There is **no** property exposed in the **DatePicker** to determine whether the user selects a date or not.

In order to track whether the user selects a date, you will have to track this yourself in the **DateSelected** *eventhandler*, by setting some other variable that you can then query later to determine whether this is a user selected date.  For example:-

```
objDatePicker.DateSelected+=((o2,e2)=>
{
blnIsUserSelectedANewDateThanDefault = true;
});
```

Note - however that should the user bring up the **DatePicker**, and select the **same** date as shown, this will **not** trigger the **DateSelected** *eventhandler* though, as the value has **not** changed.

**Update 1:-**

There is no way of hooking into **Cancel** button click that is shown using the **Xamarin.Forms** **DatePicker** control (v1.2.3x).

You can, however, create a **custom renderer** that will achieve what you want to do however.

If you go down this route, you are able to hook into the **Cancel** button click that is exposed on the **Android** **DatePickerDialog** that is shown.

Once that event is detected in your **custom renderer**, you can then **set a flag** or **raise an event** to indicate the user cancelled the date selection.

Comment: There was quite a few things mentioned in your question.  After re-reading a couple times I can see this being related sure.  The specifics of what your asking may be achievable via a custom renderer.  Can you let us know more about the scenario you are wanting to use this?  Are you ideally wanting the datepicker to effectively be non-selected, until they select it?, as it currently always shows a value?  I'm just trying to understand why you would need to know if the user selected the same date that is already presented?

Comment: The scenario is similar to employee registration. User have to enter mandatory values such as **name**, **emailid** and **date of Joining**. Since there is high probability of user selecting current date which is default and won't trigger **DateSelected**, I  need to validate whether user have entered all mandatory fields or skipped without selecting date field. Right now I use focused event handler to check whether user actually selected date, which also have a flaw in which user focus on the datepicker and chose to click on cancel I will save default date as user entered value.

Comment: Can you show how you retrieve the cancel button click in the custom renderer? I don't find a suitable method for override. There is no `onClick` in the `DatePickerRenderer`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the my findings so far:

**Android:**

SelectedDateChanged = only fires when the date has actually changed. fires on done and cancel

SelectedDate = sets property on done and cancel
unfocused= fires on done and cancel

**iOS:**

selecteddatechanged= fires every time you change date regardless of done and cancel

SelectedDate= sets property on done and cancel
unfocused = fires on done and cancel
To me this makes the control almost unusable in my project. How am I supposed to determine if the user hit done or just clicked the background to cancel the operation?